# Highcharts. Remove series label when hide

Tags: highcharts

I am looking to hide series labels when a series is hidden via the legend.

This issue is prevalent on highcharts own [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series-label/line-chart), where hiding a series leaves the name behind.

```
series : [{
name : "labelName",
data : [1,2],
label: { enabled : true } <-- this guy won't go away
}]
```

It baffles me that I can not find an answer to this question as I assume it would infuriate many, so I presume I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Definitely looks buggy to me

Comment: Same bug as this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863509/highcharts-when-disabled-in-legend-line-label-still-appears

Comment: Already fixed on master: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bp314yug/ - will be part of v6.1.1 release (in 2-3 weeks).